# How to find this element in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

The HTML is: `<pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">{ "name": "RATE_LIMIT_REACHED", "message": "Too many requests. Blocked due to rate limiting.", "debugId": "f518054e243d2" }</pre>`
Can you please help me out with this one?

Comment: Of course, it would help if you would confirm the actual url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this XPath locator:

```py
"//*[name()='pre' and(contains(@style,'RATE_LIMIT_REACHED'))]"
```

or

```py
"//*[name()='pre'][contains(@style,'RATE_LIMIT_REACHED')]"
```

The above XPath expressions are actually the same.
I think we do not need to use `name()` here, so this should work as well

```py
"//pre[contains(@style,'RATE_LIMIT_REACHED')]"
```

**UPD**
The first issue here resolved by this code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")

s = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=s)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
recaptchaTitle = "//*[contains(text(),'セキュリティチェック')]"
driver.get("https://www.paypal.com/signin?country.x=JP&locale.x=ja_JP")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "email"))).send_keys("jleonhard-bassek@t-online.de")
try:
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, recaptchaTitle)))
    print("Recaptcha detected!")
except:
    pass
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "btnNext"))).click()
try:
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[name='recaptcha']")))
    print("Recaptcha detected!!!")
except:
    pass
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "password"))).send_keys("mistery69")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "btnLogin"))).click()
try:
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[name='recaptcha']")))
    print("Recaptcha detected!!!!!!!!!")
except:
    pass
```

Comment: Please let me know if it worked. If not we will try getting better solutions

Comment: Hmm, i think it doesn't work :<

Comment: Can you share a link to that page and your code trials?

Comment: Do you have any other contact? I don't want to send it public :(

Comment: I have added you :D

Comment: @duyanhhz did you try the xpath I have given?

Answer (score 0):

Well, that depends on where the element is situated in relation to the rest of the document. If it's the only element with a `pre` tag, you can simply use this:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# ...

elem = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "pre")
```

If the page is more complex than that, you can use an XPath such as the one suggested by Prophet.

Answer (score 0):

@duyanhhz you can try the following XPath. Since the "RATE_LIMIT_REACHED" is part of visible text and not part of the `style` attribute of `pre` HTML tag:

```
//pre[contains(text(), 'RATE_LIMIT_REACHED')]
```